# I am trying to change follower status from 'requested' to 'approved' in relationship model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, table-relationships, self-reference

I have a relationship table with followed_id, follower_id, and status. I am using "has many through" in my user model to create the association. A user has many following through and is following many through a reverse relationship. The status defaults to "requested" when a user follows another user.

So then a user has a list of their followers and each has a status of "requested".

What I need in this list of followers is a link_to with a put method or a form that just finds that relationship and updates the status string to "approved". It seems like it would be pretty easy but I have been searching for days and cannot figure it out. This is what I have so far:

In the users_controller this the action to change the status from "requested" to "approved":

```
def activate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  params[:status] = {:status => 'approved'}
  @user.status = params[:user][:status]
  @user.save
  render 'show_followers'
end
```

this is in the users_controller to list the followers:

```
def followers
 @title = "Followers"
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
 render 'show_followers'
end
```

this is where I define status which is probably not right in user.rb model

```
def status
    Relationship.status.find_by_follower_id(self)
end
```

and this is the page where I show the followers:

```
      <% unless @users.empty? %>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb) %></td>
            <td><%= user.full_name %></td>
            <td><%= user.company %></td>
            <td><%= user.approval.status %></td>
        <%end%>
            <td><%= form_for @user, url: activate_user_path(@user), :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
                <%= f.submit "approve" %>
                <% end %>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <%= will_paginate @users %>
        <% end %>
```

does anyone know how I can just update that string in Relationship table to "approved"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a potential problem in your form, think it should be for `user` and not `@user` & `params[:user][:status]` in `activate` method (`params[:user][:status]` should be `nil` as it has not been defined in your method). I'd rather have a remote link alongside all followers that are to be approved, then update the status using the link, but that bit is for later.

So, the form :

```
<%= form_for user, url: activate_user_path(user), :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "approve" %>
<% end %>
```

and, assuming you've access to current user, and if not, passing current user too, i.e. `@user` via the form.

```
def activate
  user = User.find(params[:id]) # user to be approved
  relationship = current_user.relationships.where(:follower_id => user).first # relationship record that has above user as follower and current user as followed
  relationship.update_attributes!(:status => 'approved')
  # redirect to users#followers passing current_user
end
```

Comment: Thanks Prasvin, this worked great! I did need to pass '@user' as well. So that I can learn how this worked, why does it need to say '.first' when defining 'relationship' in 'activate' ?

Comment: Hmm... using `where` results in a Relation, precisely `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So, a Relation will have a collection of objects. Calling `.first` on it will return the first object, as we are to update the object. I think you got confused because `current_user.relationships.where(:follower_id => user)` only returns a single record (bear in mind that some other query using `where` could have fetched a number of records). But, even that single record is a Relation object. So, `.first` gives us that relationship object(i.e. of your Relationship class)  we wish to update.

Comment: As a side note, its better to refrain from certain words used by Rails. I'd personally rename your Relationship model (no sure that its used by Rails, but still confusing for me) to Interest or Support or a better name :) . I personally avoid creating models with name as Test, Template(currently used in one of my projects and needs to be renamed as clashes with ActionView::Template), Application & others... Its just a suggestion, that limits further confusion. OR if its confusing for you to rename, just stick with it. Use what works best, simple and effective for you.